# Detect and monitor changes to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I use Drupal, and instead of having to use the formal interface to make small changes to a site all the time, I am wondering if there is a way to determine what modifications Drupal makes to the database so that I can make them manually the next time.

For example, if I use Drupal’s interface to add a module to the site, I would like to be able to find out what database entries it changes/adds so that if I want to add another module, I can add or change the file or database entry myself instead of having to go through Druapl.

This way, I can have better control over the system as well as gain a greater understanding of how it works underneath.

My environment is Windows XP, MySQL latest stable, phpmyadmin.

Comment: Why not just use an actual RCS?

Comment: @Synetech My immediate answer is that I need to look it up.

Comment: To look what up; the modifications?

Comment: @Synetech I guess I need to try some RCS's and see which one works out.  The purpose isn't for the revisions but for the information, of course.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “information”. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Synetech That sounds accurate.  For example, if I add some new content to my website, I'd like to know where the database was altered.  If I add a new module to my site, and it alters a .php file in a different module, I'd like to know how it edited the pre-existing module.  This an okay example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3944/discussion-between-wolfpack08-and-synetech)

Comment: I tried MySQL Administrator, but the general query log still needs to be toggled.  The official MySQL documentation is really ambiguous, to the point of being nonsense.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can use the *Log Files* tab of the *Startup Variables* section of MySQL Administrator or you can just edit your `my.ini` file and set the log entries: `log="…/query.log"`, `general-log=1`, `general-log-file="…/query.log"` (which is good because you also get to see the full annotations for the settings as well as other settings).

Comment: @Synetech Cool, I got it going.  Wow, it's hard to decipher, but it's much better than going without. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `Devel node access` extension of the `Devel` module

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, man.  Thank you.  It works great.